# Cropper returns null Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery

My app has possibility to change user avatar (with latter uploading it to web service). But on some devices Cropper ("com.android.camera.action.CROP" Intent) starts, but returns null Uri. Could u point me what i've done wrong?

1st user picks photo with:

```
public static void pickPhoto(final Context context) {
    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
    ((ActionBarActivity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickImageIntent, "Select Avatar"), SettingsActivity.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_AVATAR);
}
```

Then after activity get's RESULT_OK (selected image uri) - it starts cropper:

```
public static void startCropper(final Context context, final Uri imageToCrop) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setData(imageToCrop);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    ((ActionBarActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, SettingsActivity.REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR);
}
```

which returns RESULT_OK with null getData():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData(); // uri is null on some devices
    }
}
```

My getTempFile method:

```
public static File getTempFile(Context context) {
    File cacheDir;
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    } else {
        cacheDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    }
    File file = new File(cacheDir, "temp_avatar.jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: if ( uri==null )          bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Comment: @greenapps, wouldn't it return a non-cropped original bitmap that was passed to Cropper?

Comment: Well why aren't you answering your question yourself? I really wonder why you did not try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in question comments by greenapps, it's just need to place additional check in **onActivityResult()** if uri is null and then getExtra("data"), like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (null != uri) {
            // do something with uri
        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = data.getExtra("data");
            // get uri from bitmap and do something with uri
        }
    }
}
```

Code tested in my app and works fine.